# Unable to Clone Existing Gitlab Repo

Tags: git, ssl, ssh, gitlab

I have a project on gitlab which I am trying to clone locally (Windows 7) using

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:USERNAME/projectname.git
```

But I see this error:

> Cloning into 'foldername'...
>
> GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I know that the repo definitely exists as I can see it under my GitLab account.

---

I also tried the solution posted [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/638), but I get this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://USERNAME@gitlab.com/USERNAME/projectname.git/`: SSL certificate problem: unable to get the local issuer certificate

I'm pretty sure I have had this working in the past using SSH rather than HTTPS, so not sure if this is the right route to go down.

---

I have added a `SSH` key to the project and my local machine, and have no idea where to go from here - appreciate any help or guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not working because `%USERPROFILE%` was set to some other directory which was not `C:\users\user.name\`.

I was grabbing the `ssh` key from `C:\users\user.name\`, but this key was actually related to another project and server altogether.

When executing `ssh-keygen`, I was passing in `%USERPROFILE%` as the path, not knowing that the value had changed.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more?  What is "USERPROFILE"

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` is the path to the current user's profile. If you enter that (including the percentage signs) into windows exporer url bar, it should take you to the folder. See https://superuser.com/questions/571974/userprofile-variable-not-working